# Getting a 2FA e-mail sent on Palo Alto site with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button, xpath

I am attempting to write a script that will download a file from the Palo Alto Networks website.
The script I am writing is successfully entering username and password, but then the 2FA section comes, and I am having trouble getting selenium to locate/press the "Send me the code" button.

The script I have so far is as follows:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from dotenv import dotenv_values

# Load the .env file into a variable
config = dotenv_values(".env")

# Read username and password from the environment file
username = config['USERNAME']
password = config['PASSWORD']

# URL of the Palo Alto login page
url = "https://sso.paloaltonetworks.com/"

# Path to your WebDriver (download the appropriate one for your browser)
# For Chrome, download from https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/
# webdriver_path = r"c:\Users\tdadmin\Documents\Python\PaloAlto\RegListDownload\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    # Open the login page
    driver.get(url)

    # Find the username input field and fill them
    username_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "idp-discovery-username")
    username_field.send_keys(username)

    # Submit the username
    username_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # Wait for the password field to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "okta-signin-password"))
    )

    # Find the password input field and fill them
    password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "okta-signin-password")
    password_field.send_keys(password)

    # Submit the password
    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # Wait for the 2FA page to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button .button-primary"))
    )

    # Press the button to send the e-mail
    send_2FA = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button .button-primary")
    send_2FA.click();

    # Provide an opportunity for the user to enter 2FA code manually
    # input("Please enter your 2FA code, then press Enter to continue...")

    # You may need to locate and interact with the "Submit" button after entering 2FA code

    # For example:
    # submit_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "submit_button_id")
    # submit_button.click()

    # Now, you can perform actions on the authenticated session
    # (e.g., navigate to the desired page and download a file)

finally:
    # Close the browser window
    driver.quit()
```

The xpath of the "button" I want to press is:
/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input

When I run the above code, I get the following error, which seems to tell me the element wasn't found, or it does not know how to press the "button":

```
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Python\PaloAlto\RegListDownload\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF745682142+3514994]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7452A0CE2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7451476AA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF745191860]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF74519197C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7451D4EE7]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7451B602F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7451D28F6]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7451B5D93]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF745184BDC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF745185C64]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7456AE16B+3695259]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF745706737+4057191]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7456FE4E3+4023827]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7453D04F9+689705]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7452AC048]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7452A8044]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7452A81C9]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7452988C4]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF9712A7AC4+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF97404A351+33]
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I think your css selecter for the button should be

```
".button.button-primary"
```

You current css-selecter ("button button-primary") tries to find an `element` `<button/>` en in that element find a element `<button-primary/>`.

In css you select a class by using a `.` in front of the classname. And if you want to find an element with multiple classes they should be sticked together without the use of spaces.

Comment: Whether I use 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button button-primary"))
    )
or 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input")))
It does not seem to make a difference. The button does not seem to get pressed, because no e-mail comes to my inbox.
It's followed up with send_2FA = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input")
    send_2FA.click();

Comment: Edited the question to include the suggestion of @Siebe.
Also provided the output that logically comes after the wait has ended.